# jquery slideshow cycle options

Tags: jquery, slideshow, cycle

I have the following jquery slideshow code working fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    speed: 1000,
    timeout: 5000
});
</script>
```

I was just wondering if and how I can use the jquery cycle options to add Prev & Next buttons to the slides? I see the prev: & next: options, but exactly how are they coded?

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is just calling the jQuery cycle plugin.
So you need to find the different plugin options in that [plugin reference page](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html)
The code for prev and next is written [here](http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle.all.js)

```
if (opts.next)
    $(opts.next).bind(opts.prevNextEvent,function(){return advance(opts,1);});
if (opts.prev)
    $(opts.prev).bind(opts.prevNextEvent,function(){return advance(opts,0);});
```

Comment: I did, they are prev: & next:. When I added them, the slidesow did not display

Comment: Have you tried with this code?$('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx:     'fade',
    speed:  '1000',
    timeout: 500,
    next:   '#next2',
    prev:   '#prev2'
});

Comment: Sayan,added your code but I do not see the Prev & Next links on the slideshow

Comment: Where do I add your code:if (opts.next)
    $(opts.next).bind(opts.prevNextEvent,function(){return advance(opts,1);});
if (opts.prev)
    $(opts.prev).bind(opts.prevNextEvent,function(){return advance(opts,0);});

Answer (score 0):

Try like this 
add buttons

```
<a id="prev" href="#">Prev</a> 
<a id="next" href="#">Next</a>

$('#slideshow').cycle({ 
     fx: 'fade',
    speed: 1000,
    timeout: 5000,
    prev:   '#prev', //id of buttons
    next:   '#next', 
});
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/LvBRA/1/

Comment: I was hoping to overlay them on the slides

Comment: @John you can apply css to both off them

Comment: Thanks Manish. I think I'm way over my head on this one.